# Shipping Program w/ classes C++, issues

Tags: c++

I am having issues with this class, where the shipping cost is $.77 per pound, and the sum of the dimensions cannot be more than 150 units , and the package weight cannot exceed 80 lb. everything seems to be working, except the price, which returns as 0 every time , regardless of the weight.

```
class Box {
  private:
          int h , wid , l , tots;
          double wei , p;
  public :

         Box ( int height , int width ,int length , double weight ){
             h = height ;
             wid = width ;
             l = length ;
             wei = weight ;
             };

         Box () {
             h = 0;
             wid = 0 ;
             l = 0;
             };
             wei = 0;
             p=0;
             tots=0;



         void seth (int height) {
              h = height;
              };
         void setwid (int width) {
              wid = width ;
              };
         void setl (int length) {
              l = length;
              };
         void setwei (double weight) {
              wei = weight;
              };
         void settots (int totalsize) {
              tots = totalsize;
              };

         int getarea (){
             int answer;
             answer = (h + wid + l);
             answer = tots;
             return tots;
             }
         void getdata (){ 
             cout << "Please enter the height of the box: " << endl;
             cin >> h ;
             cout << "please enter the width of the box: " << endl;
             cin >> wid ;
             cout << "please enter the length of the box: " << endl;
             cin >> l ;
             cout << "please enter the weight of the box: " << endl;
             cin >> wei ;
             };

         void findlimit () {
                 if (((h + wid + l) > 150) && (wei > 80)) {
                    cout << "box is too large and too heavy" <<endl;
                    }
                 else {
                         if (h + wid + l > 150) {
                    cout << "box is too large" <<endl;
                    }
                    else {
                         if (wei > 80){
                          cout << "box is too heavy" <<endl;
                          }
                          else {
                               cout << "box is OK" << endl;
                               }
                               }
                               }
                               };

         void printcost(){
              cout << "shipping will cost: $" << p << endl; 
              };   

  };
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You never calculate the price `p`, so it's not so odd that it is 0. Add a calculation to the print out:

```
void printcost(){
          cout << "shipping will cost: $" << (0.77 * p.wei) << endl; 
          };
```

Or something similar.

Also in the second constructor some variables have been placed after the closing bracket:

```
Box () {
             h = 0;
             wid = 0 ;
             l = 0;
             };
             wei = 0;
             p=0;
             tots=0;
```

Move the last three variables inside the constructor block.